# Is there a glibc-compat or equivalent for CentOS 8?

Tags: glibc, compatibility

I'm a new maintainer for an old codebase written in C++, targeting the C++0x standard, with several gcc and g++ dependencies in the code. I'm concerned about keeping the dependencies of this program patched after CentOS 7 is EOL. Granted, that's 4 years away, but it's better to plan...

One of the many problems with this codebase is it depends on [GNU Pth](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/). This library is unmaintained upstream since 2006, and these days new software should be using Boost coroutines or something like that for an equivalent behavior, or just use pthreads.

I'm 100% sure that either our use of Pth, or Pth itself, is dependent upon a bug or an incompatible change introduced into glibc between version 2.17 (on CentOS 7, which works fine) and 2.27 (on Ubuntu 18.04, which breaks our software). The problem is extremely pernicious to debug, even with full source code and debug symbols, because Pth's operating model constantly clobbers the stack, making it difficult to tell how the program got to a particular failure mode.

I have isolated the problem to the glibc version, and have also tried it on CentOS 8, which uses glibc 2.28. To me this seems not to be a regression, but a deliberate change, even though it breaks backwards compatibility.

The observed crash on recent glibc isn't what I want to focus on here. I would like to know if there are any repos out there with a longer EOL date than CentOS 7 that plan to support glibc 2.17 on CentOS 8, or Ubuntu 20.04.

Of course, I could just compile glibc 2.17 and statically link it into the binary, but that would mean I no longer receive security updates to that version of glibc. Since this software listens directly on a port reachable from the public Internet, I don't like that idea at all.

I might end up git bisecting to find the exact version of glibc that causes the breakage, but even then, the burden would be on *my* shoulders to maintain security patches of whichever version of glibc I settle on. One of the things I like about enterprise distros is that you get many years of fully ABI and API compatible security updates, so you can take your time and resolve your application software forward-porting issues whenever it's convenient. It may seem crazy, but I'd like to extend that timeline beyond June 2024 (the end of security updates for CentOS 7).

What are my options for continuing to stick with an old but patched version of glibc? Or, in the absence of any good options, am I better off using the time I have now until June 2024 to just solve the underlying issue so an upgrade is possible?

Comment: I wonder if you're seeing https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159238/2072269?

Comment: Why don't you rebuild your app with the current version of glibc granted you can change it to make it compatible?

Comment: @muru The program compiles fine on modern glibc systems with very recent (9.x) gcc. Does the issue you linked to have any runtime impact?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov The "ability" to change something doesn't make it easy. I can, and have, rebuilt the program against recent glibc/libstdc++ using recent gcc. It compiles fine. The program crashes in a way that is extremely difficult to debug, as mentioned in the question. If the crash were even just moderately hard to debug, I would fix the crash instead of trying to stay on glibc 2.17. But here I am, because I've spent close to 100 hours trying to solve this with no success.

Comment: Maybe you should give the job to someone else? Debugging an issue for 100 hours without success sounds excessive.

Comment: Have you looked into porting from Pth to Boost or pthreads? That would probably fix the issue you’re seeing, and remove an obsolete dependency... Other than that, to get support beyond 2024 I suspect you’d have to switch to RHEL 7 and ask for an ELS.

Comment: I would also vote for switching from Pth to different library which has the bug fixed. Debugging for 100 hours is something that might happen on complicated systems with threading (40+ hours sometimes happens to me too).